# How to create a dictionary to reverse lookup list items that each have sets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, set, list-comprehension

I have test names in a list like this in Python v2.7:

```
all_tests = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', ..., 'testN']
```

And for each test name, I can lookup a set of properties that the test has:

```
series['test'] = {'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', ..., 'propN'}
```

E.g.,

```
series['test1'] = {'yellow', 'blue', 'orange'}
series['test2'] = {'blue', 'red', 'black'}
series['test3'] = {'yellow', 'green', 'black'}
```

Now, I wish to reverse the direction and create a dictionary from properties to the set of tests that have that property.

So for the above example three tests, I'd like to create this dictionary:

```
result = {
          'yellow': {'test1', 'test3'},
          'blue':   {'test1', 'test2'},
          'orange': {'test1'},
          'red':    {'test2'},
          'black':  {'test2', 'test3'}
          'green':  {'test3'}
}
```

I imagine there is a way with list comprehension to build the dictionary, but I'm unclear how to do so.  I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
tuple( series[test], test ) for test in all_tests
```

But don't know how to put that into the result dictionary and have the set of dictionary values for each key, keep getting added to.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward looping solution using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
for k,v in series.items():
    for prop in v:
        d[prop].add(k)
print(d)
#defaultdict(set,
#            {'black': {'test2', 'test3'},
#             'blue': {'test1', 'test2'},
#             'green': {'test3'},
#             'orange': {'test1'},
#             'red': {'test2'},
#             'yellow': {'test1', 'test3'}})
```

---

Another approach using `pandas`

First convert `series` into a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({k: list(v) for k, v in series.items()})
print(df)
#    test1  test2   test3
#0    blue   blue   black
#1  orange  black   green
#2  yellow    red  yellow
```

Next [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) the DataFrame, `groupby` the `value` and use `set` as the aggregate function:

```
print(pd.melt(df).groupby("value", as_index=True).agg(set))
#              variable
#value                 
#black   {test3, test2}
#blue    {test1, test2}
#green          {test3}
#orange         {test1}
#red            {test2}
#yellow  {test1, test3}
```

Finally to go back to a dictionary, call `to_records()` and apply the `dict` constructor:

```
print(dict(pd.melt(df).groupby("value", as_index=True).agg(set).to_records()))
#{'black': {'test2', 'test3'},
# 'blue': {'test1', 'test2'},
# 'green': {'test3'},
# 'orange': {'test1'},
# 'red': {'test2'},
# 'yellow': {'test1', 'test3'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that creates a regular dictionary:

```
series = {
    'test1': {'yellow', 'blue', 'orange'},
    'test2': {'blue', 'red', 'black'},
    'test3': {'yellow', 'green', 'black'},
}

result = {}
for name, props in series.items():
    for prop in props:
        result.setdefault(prop, set()).add(name)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
{'black': set(['test2', 'test3']),
 'blue': set(['test1', 'test2']),
 'green': set(['test3']),
 'orange': set(['test1']),
 'red': set(['test2']),
 'yellow': set(['test1', 'test3'])}
```

Another alternative to get same result:

```
from itertools import chain

properties = set(chain.from_iterable(series.values()))  # All possible.
result = {prop: {name for name, props in series.items() if prop in props}
                    for prop in properties}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a set or any iterable containing all properties, e.g. `all_props`?
Then your reverse dict could be created with

```
rev_series = {p: {k for k, v in series.items() if p in v} for p in all_props}
```

If not:

```
all_props = set()
for s in series.values():
    all_props = all_props.union(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a set of all the available colors. Then, for each color create a set of the series entries that contain that color:

```
colors = set( color for colors in series.values() for color in colors ) 
result = { color:set(test for test in series if color in series[test]) for color in colors }
print(result)
# {'green': {'test3'}, 'red': {'test2'}, 'black': {'test2', 'test3'}, 'yellow': {'test1', 'test3'}, 'orange': {'test1'}, 'blue': {'test1', 'test2'}}
```